# Validator.w3.org doesn't understand my HTML 4.01+RDFa

Tags: validation, w3c-validation, html4, rdfa

I have following code in the page head:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/html401-rdfa-1.dtd">
<html xml:lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->language; ?>" dir="<?php echo $this->direction; ?>">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8">
```

If I try to validate this page with Validator.w3.org and do it with automatic doctype detecting, I get 174 errors and the doctype is shown as -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01+RDFa 1.0//EN. Here is the [validation result](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fbuchon.de%2Freise%2Fbuecher%2Fberlin%2Fitem%2F86-berlin-entdecken.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3+http%3A%2F%2Fvalidator.w3.org%2Fservices).

Then if setting the doctype manually to HTML 4.01+RDFa 1.1 and [revalidate the page](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://buchon.de/reise/buecher/berlin/item/86-berlin-entdecken.html&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=HTML%204.01%20%2b%20RDFa%201.1&group=0&verbose=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.3%20http://validator.w3.org/services), the doctype is shown as HTML 4.01 Transitional, there are 2 errors and 2 warnings: Unable to Determine Parse Mode and DOCTYPE Override in effect! The validator seems not to understand my doctype and writes:

> The detected DOCTYPE Declaration >!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01+RDFa 1.0//EN" "hxxp://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/html401-rdfa-1.dtd"< has been suppressed and the DOCTYPE for "HTML 4.01 + RDFa 1.1" inserted instead...

If setting the validator up to show the source code, so i see, that the validator has a little bit another code, as the the page has. The validator changes the first line of the code to

```html
<!DOCTYPE ><!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01+RDFa 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/html401-rdfa-1.dtd"> -->
```

and comments my right doctype out...`

Would somebody point me to the right doctype (or right syntax/workaround)?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why you are not using a more mainstream RDFa doctype such as:

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">`

or even the more simple HTML5 doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: I deleted any doctype from my page and then tested one by one all doctypes available at Validator.w3.org. And so i finded, that with HTML 4.01 + RDFa 1.1 i got minimum validation errors.BTW, i tested both of your suggestions: with first i get more then 300 errors, with html5 i get 30 errors...